# convert doc to docx without using New-Object -COM "Word.Application"

Tags: powershell, ms-word, docx, doc

I would like to know if there is any option to convert doc files to docx.
I try to use New-Object -COM "Word.Application" but there is many edge cases like files with password, opens file, files that when you open you have to choose how to open the file.
So I decided to find anther way to make the conversion.
(I have more then 1 million of doc file to convert..)

Comment: why you even want to do this? doc files are upward compatible.

Comment: It will save me a lot GB, I want to do it on external storage.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look to google first, it exists much *online* or *batch* converters. You can try [Docx to Doc Batch Converter](http://www.pioverpi.net/2009/07/15/docx2doc-batch-converter/)

Answer (score 0):

"there is many edge cases like files with password" would mean that you cannot open the file.  To convert a file, you would have to open it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a utility known as DocTo https://github.com/tobya/DocTo as mentioned in this StackExchange question https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/74930/194688

The flags I found useful to solve this problem

```
.\docto.exe --inputfile ".\" --outputfile "C:\somenewpath\" --format wdFormatDocumentDefault --outputextension .docx -C 65535
```

- `--inputfile ".\"` is the folder containing your .doc files
- `--outputfile "C:\somenewpath\"` is the folder to output your converted .docx files
- `--format wdFormatDocumentDefault` tells docto to convert to Word's default format
- `--outputextension .docx` is neccessary if output is a directory
- `-C 65535` will ensure the converted file will be in the latest version of Word